# How to use Dataclass when using a dict as one of the fields?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Dataclass is changing dict across objects in the following code. What can i do to not have that behaviour?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict

@dataclass
class Test:
      param: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory = lambda: ({"xyz": 0}))

test1_obj = Test()
test2_obj = Test()
test1_obj.param["xyz"] = 10
print(test1_obj.param["xyz"])
print(test2_obj.param["xyz"])
```

Both the lines printed return 10, while i wanted test2_obj to still return 0. How can i change in the construct of dataclass?

** this is fine behaviour on 3.7 version and higher **

Comment: With my Python 3.7.5 under Linux, I am getting the expected correct output of 10 and 0. Which version of Python do you have?

Comment: It worked for me. I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using Python 3.8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by many users here, this works fine on python 3.7 and higher versions.